# Plot 3D mesh in Maxima without colored surface

Tags: plot, gnuplot, maxima

I have a 1-dimensional list `x` in Maxima with 16 different elements, and plotted every possible product of two elements as a 3D plot:

```
g(u,v) := float('x[round(u)]*'x[round(v)]);
plot3d(g(u,v),[u,1,16],[v,1,16],[grid,15,15]);
```

Which yields this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKwfe.png

My desired result is having *only* the contour lines, i.e. the mesh. I don't want the coloured surface.

This seems like a trivial task, but the manual is very unclear on this. It says that usually, you already have only the mesh, but this isn't the case.

Using wxMaxima 12.04.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the key is to get the Gnuplot output file to contain the line

```
set style data lines
```

Maxima has its own idea about "set style ..." which you can see by

```
set_plot_option ([plot_format, gnuplot]);
```

and then inspecting the output file ($HOME/maxout.gnuplot by default). I don't know how to convince Maxima to output a different style command. As a last resort you could edit maxout.gnuplot by hand.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a bit about gnuplot now, and managed to load the maxout.gnuplot file. Unfortunately, neither adding the line before, after, or instead of the line "set style line 100 lt -1 lw 1" modified the picture. It still looks the same.

Comment: @user2009388 Try cutting out the "with pm3d" on the line which looks like "splot <stuff> with pm3d", so it is just "splot <stuff>". I find that when I make those 2 changes, I see just the lines and not the colored surface.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for! Oddly enough, even if I set `[gnuplot_pm3d,false]` with maxima, there's still `with pm3d` included in maxout.gnuplot

Comment: @user2009388 Glad to help. Thanks for the info about gnuplot_pm3d -- I have filed a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

```
g(u,v) := float('x[round(u)]*'x[round(v)]);
plot3d(g(u,v),[u,1,16],[v,1,16],[grid,15,15], [palette, false]);
```

The [palette, false] option turns off surface coloring and draws only the mesh. But you'll still get hidden line removal, which Maxima automatically turns on.

To get a transparent wire mesh, do this:

```
plot3d(g(u,v),[u,1,16],[v,1,16],[grid,15,15],  [palette, false], 
[gnuplot_postamble, "unset hidden3d;"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This would've been an easier way, but unfortunately isn't what I was looking for. There's still a non-transparent white surface.

Comment: I just get the error `set_plot_option: unknown plot option: gnuplot_postamble`. This seems to be a newer feature, but I'm not able to run the most recent version of Maxima on my system. I'll try again when possible. (Currently working: wxMaxima 13.4.0, Maxima 5.30.0)

Comment: OK. It does work in my version (Maxima 5.35.1, wxMaxima 14.12.0).